# How can I proxy form data using http-proxy-middleware?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, proxy, reverse-proxy

I created a proxy on firebase using http-proxy-middleware.
It works on GET requests but does not pass the data I send via body in POST requests. I did some research and added the "onProxyReq" method to the options. This way it works when I send json body, but not when I send form data.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const {
  createProxyMiddleware,
  fixRequestBody,
} = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var restream = function (proxyReq, req, res, options) {
  if (req.body) {
    let bodyData = JSON.stringify(req.body);

    proxyReq.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    proxyReq.setHeader("Content-Length", Buffer.byteLength(bodyData));
    proxyReq.write(bodyData);
  }
};

app.use(
  "/",
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: "http://IPADDRESS:8080/api",
    changeOrigin: true,
    onProxyReq: restream,
    bodyParser: false,
  })
);

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This code works with json body.

Changing "application/json" to "multipart/form-data" doesn't work.

All I want is to redirect the JWT token in the header and the FormData in the body.
What should be the best way for this?

Comment: Hi, is any luck? I got similar issue